# Symbol error in java application using netbeans 6.8 when adding a shared project to library

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans6.8

I have a project which has shared functionality between three other projects and have linked these to existing projects as I normally would using the add project functionality of the libraries folder.

This all used to work however when I started up Netbeans yesterday it just wasn't working as in the other projects won't compile even though the projects are linked. It can recognise the packages - just the actual classes themselves were not recognised... and to add to the weirdness some of the classes are getting picked up fine.

I have checked the dist folder of the shared project and the Shared.jar file exists. Also I have checked the Jar and the other classes that are not being recognises are there also.

Any suggestions?

[alt text http://inverse.seednet.eu/snaps/duvc6r.png](http://inverse.seednet.eu/snaps/duvc6r.png)

**Solution**

I had to reinstall netbeans to get this solution resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a bug in 6.8, as I have ran into the same problem and I only solved it by recreating the project, was a fairly fast process, only had to re-import the sources and then add the JARs on which it depends.

To confirm this case you only have to see the imports that NetBeans did not find, and then go to the included JARs and see if the class really is there, if it is, then it should be able to find it.

Comment: Fixed the problem by reinstalling netbeans :/ how bizarre is that!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have AbstractCrawler.class compiled to its output location as well?

Comment: By that do you mean does the Shared project output the build folder? It does do that.