# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds in sorting

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I've written my sorting problem as follows, but i am getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.
which i'm not able to figure it out. plz help.

```
System.out.println("Enter the total no of digits to sort:-  ");

n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
x = new int[n];

System.out.println("Enter the elements:- ");

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    x[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if(x[j] > x[j+1])  //ascending order
        {
            temp = x[j];
            x[j] = x[j+1];
            x[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what's the size of x[]?

Comment: size of x is initialized during runtime.

Comment: Yep, my question is no longer relevant since your updated provided the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `j` goes up to `n`, `j+1` is out of bound. You need to change it to

```
for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)
```

Doing so would make sure that `x[j+1]` is within bounds.

Comment: i did the same program in netbeans n gt an error saying..."java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javaapplication3/Main
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1"........help on this plz.

Comment: @jhe This is likely to be an issue with your netbeans project configuration. Here is a [link to a relevant discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2702185/335858).

Answer (score 0):

Error is here:

```
if(x[j] > x[j+1]) {
 ....
```

Because `j+1` is equal to`n`

Make this change:

```
 for(j=0;j + 1<n;j++) {
  ...
```

Comment: Nop, `j+1` IS `n` on the last loop. Though when setting `int[n]`, the last index is `n - 1`. So `int[n]` or its equivalent on the last loop `int[j+1]` will be outOfBound. *Example*: int[4] creates keys {0, 1, 2, 3}